# how to bind hash table to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hashtable

hi i have a hash table with following set of values

```
int    ID    1
string Name  ram
list   date  2/3/2011
             5/3/2011
```

Code:

```
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemStyle Width="200px"> </ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>                
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>                                     
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>

 its throws error in bind statement
```

Comment: Hashtable class contains KeyValuePair items. Could you be more precise with your hashtable structure?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Repeator` or `GridView` or `Datalist` control to bind the `list` (dates) inside the `ItemTemplate` of `GridView`.

Comment: You can Google any one of these controls. There are literally thousands of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables have `keys` and `values` so you can't bind your grid using the key names (as you are doing) because the key names are not properties of the hash table. If anything, you could have columns bound to `Key` and `Value`; however, your data has a `List` of things (dates) and the Gridview won't know how to bind this list to one column. As AVD suggested, you need to have an item template and inside it, have another gridview if you want to bind a data structure like this to a grid view.